# How to compile a shared object that statically links a library that was not compiled with -fPIC?

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

I cannot recompile the library in question as it is being provided by a vendor that does not offer source code, only their `.a` file.

Is there a way to include their static library in my shared object that requires `-fPIC`?

When attempting this I generate this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /path/to/lib/libtheirs.a(theirs.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /path/to/lib/libtheirs.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

Comment: Alas, you have encountered one of the most annoying issues *ever*.

Comment: Take a look at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808691/can-i-build-a-shared-library-by-linking-static-libraries>.

It seems to have some dependency on the platform.