# How do I build `shared_lib` with snappy?

Tags: alpine-linux, rocksdb

Does anyone know how to build shared_lib with snappy ?

In last 3 hours I tried:

1. Setting env variable `WITH_SNAPPY`
2. Editing `thirdparty.inc` and changing `USE_SNAPPY_DEFAULT` to 1
3. Passing variable to make via `make shared_lib EXTRA_CFLAGS=-DSNAPPY`
4. Dancing with tambourine.

Nothing helps. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out flags don't matter. [build_detect_platform](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/build_tools/build_detect_platform) simply detects installed libraries in the system by compiling small pieces of code.

I was building RocksDB in Alpine Lunux so packages I had to install were `zlib zlib-dev bzip2 bzip2-dev snappy snappy-dev lz4 lz4-dev zstd zstd-dev jemalloc jemalloc-dev libtbb-dev libtbb`

More details in [Docker script](https://hub.docker.com/r/expert/rocksdb/~/dockerfile/) I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

S. the response her: [Can I build a shared library by linking static libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808691/can-i-build-a-shared-library-by-linking-static-libraries)

You will need the object files created during the compilation of snappy